# Modelling tool for very large models?

Tags: software-development, modeling

Are there any tools especially designed for very large/complex domain/database models? I am speaking of 200+ or 500+ entities/tables?

Common standard tools don't cope well with this amount, both in terms of performance and usability.

Comment: Probably be good to list the 'common standard tools' rather than assume people agree on what those are. Also do you care about operating system, pricing, open sourceness?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the tools from larger vendors easily handle such amounts. I have no experience above 5,000 tables but up to that amount it should be possible. Some samples: Oracle Designer, ERwin. I myself use yEd plus an own case-tool. I find the essential feature that makes large volume manageable that a tool can auto-layout and auto-group tables that have strong relations between them.

For my interest: what problems are you running into? Can you add those to your question?

Comment: In the past I was using ObjectMapper2005 which had a terrible performance for larger models, in .NET development we use integrated editors from Visual Studio which have a terrible perf. as well, but don't even have any *concepts* for larger models (e.g. no packaging/namespaces!!)

Comment: A perfect tool provide higher abstractions for layering relations.

Comment: Yes, when you can bring similar relations together it gets more easily readable in general. For some entities, like Person, you will find a relationship absolutely everywhere so these can be placed in a "information infrastructure". PS. So far we are using our own objectmapper for ORM. Most CASE-tools allow you to query their data and generate your own C# data access layer.